# Mind mapping software with no presentation editing

Tags: graphs, mind-mapping

I am looking for some mind mapping or graph making software that EXPLICITLY DISALLOWS the user to alter elements of visual presentation on a per-vertex/node basis. Basically, if I have to set the size of a box, or position of the box on a grid, or picking between a rectangle, square, circle, or rounded rectangle, I don't want to hear about it. The software should algorithmically generate all elements of layout and presentation based on meaningful properties defined on each vertex or edge.

However, I also don't want to be limited to a tree structure. I want to be able to create multiple roots, and to draw relationship edges between arbitrary nodes on different trees, or the same tree. I would like to use a GUI in the process of adding nodes, editing properties, and creating edges.

The closest thing I've found to this is [Mindly](http://www.mindlyapp.com/features), but this does enforce a tree structure, so relationships cannot be made between arbitrary nodes.

I'll accept any publicly available software that runs on a present-day desktop or mobile OS.

Comment: What OS must it run on? Any price limit when it comes to paid software? Any other specifics it should support (e.g. embedding other documents, hyperlinking to the "outer world", …)?

Comment: @Izzy I don't think I'm suffering from an abundance of choices here. I'll accept any publicly available software that runs on a present-day desktop or mobile OS.

Comment: Argument accepted – just needed to make sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Me and my friend are building a collaborative idea development tool which works as a mindmap, where any node can be opened as a kanban board. Because we put collaboration as a major thing, we decided on purpose to not allow dragging nodes, changing layouts, etc. It's all done automatically and cannot be changed. You can still color code nodes and collapse subtrees, but it's only for you — other collaborators will not see it. The idea was that we need mindmap to break down bigger things into smaller parts and keeping the context while jumping from a very high-level whole-project look to kanban and specific tasks and get back.

You can try it here: [todo.space](http://cubismore.com) — it's free.

Although it enforces tree structure and doesn't have links.